# Remove event form Elapsed timer

Tags: c#, timer

I am using `System.Timers` to make a `Timer`

```
Timer timer = new Timer(1000);
timer.Elapsed += Func;
timer.Elapsed += Func2;
timer.Start();
```

So far everything works fine , but when I want to unsubscribe the `Func2` it doesn't work, it keeps calling `Func2` like if I didn't unsubscribe it :

```
timer.Elapsed -= Func2;
```

Am i doing it wrong , and if so, how would I do it correctly ?

Comment: That code should be working to remove Func2.  Can you elaborate as to what exactly it is doing wrong?  Throwing an error, still calling Func2 at every interval, etc?

Comment: yeah it keeps calling `Func2` , as like I didn't remove it.

Comment: Where are you doing the removal?

Comment: from an other thread

Comment: Doesn't that seem worth mentioning in the question??? Your question, as it is, can't be reproduced

Comment: My first guess would be that you have a timing issue that is causing the removal to register after Func2 gets called, but with a 1 second interval that should really only be happening once, then the calls should stop.  I'd need to see the full code or a reproducible sample to give you more help.

Comment: Please make the absolute smallest possible compliable program to demonstrate your problem (so we could just copy and paste the code and run it) and put it in as a edit to your question. It will greatly help get you answers.

Answer (score 0):

Do unsubscribing using BeginInvoke after checking if InvokeRequired. Seems like you aren't doing it on the right thread.

Comment: I believe since System.Threading.Timer isn't a form control, it can be manipulated cross thread (and in fact doesn't even have an InvokeRequired property). If it were a cross-thread access issue, it would be throwing an exception instead of just ignoring the removal.

Comment: He is not using System.Threading.Timer he is using System.Timers.Timer. I have seen in the past cases where exception is not thrown but action is ignored. Please refer here, a very good explanation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx#S2